# Использование плейбуков для определенных хостов из инвернтарного файла в Ansible

Tags: python, ansible

Добрый вечер. У меня есть инвентарный файл следующего вида:

```
[main]
cl-main    ansible_host=10.0.9.700    ansible_user=ansible    

[cluster]
cl-node1   ansible_host=10.0.9.701    ansible_user=ansible
cl-node2   ansible_host=10.0.9.702    ansible_user=ansible
cl-node3   ansible_host=10.0.9.703    ansible_user=ansible
```

В директории /playbooks лежит набор плейбуков. В hosts указано, где будет выполняться данный плейбук.

Плейбук для примера:

```
---
- hosts: cl-main 
  roles:
    - kiask.cassandra
```

Что если я хочу выполнить плейбук для хоста cl-node1? Необхоимо сменить адресат в самом плейбуке (что не есть хорошо) или же это можно сделать одной командой выбрав хост из инвентарного файла?

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте параметр `-l`, `--limit`:

```
  -l SUBSET, --limit=SUBSET
                        further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern
```

Для описания шаблона (pattern) в Ansible используется [следующий синтаксис](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html#patterns):

Для одного хоста или группы:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -l 'cl-node1'
```

Несколько хостов можно перечислить через `:`:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -l 'cl-node1:cl-node2:cl-node3'
```

Можно указать диапазон:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -l 'cl-node[1-2]'
```

Можно использовать маски:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -l 'cl-node*'
```

Ещё есть пересечение множеств, отрицание, и всё это можно комбинировать. Примеры можно найти в [документации](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_patterns.html#patterns).

Кроме этого, можно [задавать inventory динамически](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html). Например, чтобы выполнить плейбук на локальной машине:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i 'localhost,'
```

Обратите внимание: запятая после `localhost` важна, т.к. это список!

Comment: Я думаю, нужно на этот ответ галку переставить.

Comment: Спасибо, почерпунл много полезной информации для себя. Да и для всех остальных эта тема, пожалуй, будет интересна.

Answer (score 1):

Командной строкой нельзя выбрать меньше, чем группу. Один точечный хост не выбрать, видимо идеологически ansible затачивали сразу под группы хостов.

Когда необходимо такое (а необходимо часто) часто применяется следующий типовой способ: передача параметра хоста в `extra-vars`.

В плейбуке пишете что-то типа:

```
---
# This playbook updates all packages.

- name: yum update all packages
  hosts: '{{ target | default("all") }}'
  become: true
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: yum update all
    yum: name=* state=latest
```

И вызываете его для конкретного хоста командой:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_production yum_update_all.yml --extra-vars "target=cl-node2"
```

Если опустить переменную, то команда выполнится по дефолту на всех серверах:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts_production yum_update_all.yml
```

Я к такому способу уже привык, давно все плейбуки начинаю с подобного вступления.

Да, вместо `default("all")` можете указать какую-либо группу, например, указать `default("cluster")`.

Comment: Благодарю вас, хорошо разжевали!))

Comment: Как нельзя меньше чем группу? А `ansible-playbook ... -l 'host1:host2:hostblabla*'`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Надо же, век живи -- век учись. Не знал, спасибо!

Comment: А этот способ хорош для ситуации, когда нужно запускать плейбук только с явно указанным хостом. Для этого нужно будет убрать `| default("all")`